# Heroku: What will be the hostname and port of my deployed socket.io app

Tags: javascript, heroku, socket.io

I have a socket.io app that I want to host on heroku. This is my first heroku deployment and I am not sure what is the hostname and port of my app is. This is how the server.js file is :

```
const http = require('http').createServer();
const questions = require('./Questions');
const dares = require('./Dares');
const rathers = require('./WYRather');
const nhie = require('./NHIE');

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: { origin: "*"}
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:8080");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The hostname is `${your-project-name}.herokuapp.com`.

The port cannot be determined until it gets deployed, which will be `process.env.PORT`.